# Imagick PHP class for combining multiple pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, upload, imagick

When I upload two pdf files at once these are stored in `$uploaddir` where `$uploaddir="/uploaddir/";`.

The files are saved through the following path:

```
string(20) "/uploaddir/test1.pdf"
string(20) "/uploaddir/test2.pdf"
```

which are the array of `$testfile`

I'm using the following `Imagick` code to combine these two files

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readimage($testfile);  
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');
$im->writeImages($uploaddir . 'test.pdf', true); 
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

the problem is that the combined file `test.pdf` is outputting the last file `test2.pdf` of the `$_FILES` array.

What's going wrong there? Is there any specific `Imagick` PHP class for this task?

If you down vote this question don't forget to mention the reason for it if you don't want to prove yourself a freak. I shall appreciate any good reason for down voting it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything went fine after I rearranged the array like,

```
Array

(
    [0] => /uploaddir/test1.pdf
    [1] => /uploaddir/test2.pdf
)
```

so that all the array values are parsed by `foreach` loop later on.